# Javascript: What is the purpose of ()?

Tags: javascript

I was come across the code which was written in following way:

```
var myStr = ('abc');
console.log(myStr)  // output: 'abc'
myStr === 'abc'  // true
```

What was the use of () in above example?

Comment: There is no purpose in your example. It's a grouping operator and you are grouping no operations together, so it's equivalent to not using it. Same as how `5 + (1)` is the same as `5 + 1`

Comment: I usually use it when using arrow operators that return an object literal. `const fn = () => ({a: 1})`

Comment: Can we not fill the comments up with examples of how grouping operators are used in obscure contexts that the question isn't asking about?